# Cannot submit for production in Google Actions

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I created a trivia app in Google Actions following this [link](https://developers.google.com/actions/templates/trivia). I followed all the steps but when trying to submit for production (officially launch the Action to all the Google Assistant users) I get the following error:

[image: Error received when trying to submit the Action]

I double checked all the constrains they suggest in the tutorial (like using photos of a specific size, having proper *Privacy Policy* and *Terms of Service* , checking that the app name is not taken etc).

*One thing to mention: this is not a network issue, as I tried from multiple PCs and networks.*

Is there a log file where I can look and pinpoint the issue? Or somebody else encountered this issue?

Comment: Please reach out to the support team: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Comment: Thanks @Leon Nicholls . I've filled the support page. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested I've reached out Google support team (https://developers.google.com/actions/support/) . They answered really fast.

The fix was simple: make another copy of the spreadsheet used and try again.